# Dymola Python Interface - simulateExtendedModel: How to set up parameters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, modelica, dymola

I'm trying to set up parameters and initial values via the dymola python interface. When I'm trying to set up one parameter/value it works perfectly, but when trying to set up more than one value it doesn't work.

Working:

```
output = dymola.simulateExtendedModel("Wall_to_Py.Test", 0.0, 60000.0, 3326, 0.0, "Dassl", 0.0001, 0, "TryWall", ["rCWall2.T[mNode]"], TstartWall, ["rCWall2.T[mNode]"], True)
```

Not working:

```
output = dymola.simulateExtendedModel("Wall_to_Py.Test", 0.0, 60000.0, 3326, 0.0, "Dassl", 0.0001, 0, "TryWall", ["rCWall2.n", "rCWall2.T[mNode]"], [nWall, TstartWall], ["rCWall2.n", "rCWall2.T[mNode]"], True)
```

I'm using this:

```
simulateExtendedModel(problem, startTime, stopTime, numberOfIntervals, outputInterval, method, tolerance, fixedstepsize, resultFile, initialNames, initialValues, finalNames, autoLoad)
```

Parameters:

```
problem (str) – Name of model, e.g. Modelica.Mechanics.Rotational.Components.Clutch.
startTime (float) – Start of simulation.
stopTime (float) – End of simulation.
numberOfIntervals (int) – Number of output points.
outputInterval (float) – Distance between output points.
method (str) – Integration method.
tolerance (float) – Tolerance of integration.
fixedstepsize (float) – Fixed step size for Euler.
resultFile (str) – Where to store result.
initialNames (str[]) – Parameters and start-values to set. Dimension [:].
initialValues (float[]) – Parameter values. Dimension [size(initialNames, 1)].
finalNames (str[]) – Variables at end-point. Dimension [:].
autoLoad (bool) – Auto load result.
```

I don't understand how the syntax has to be:

```
initialValues (float[]) – Parameter values. Dimension [size(initialNames, 1)].
```

Comment: Is mNode a parameter? 
For the first working one - does changing TstartWall really influence the simulation? 
I would expect that you needed a literal index in that case, e.g. ["rCWall2.T[12]"] - so I am a bit surprised about the working case.

Comment: Oh you are right. This doesn't work. Only when I'm declaring it like you said. But my problem is, that my model is a wall with n layers and for each layer I have length l[n], heat capacity cp[n] and so on,  I would like to load these parameters from a text file. So isn't there a possibility to define the parameters (via python interface) depending on n?

Answer (score 2):

So as far as I can see you currently have to generate a string-vector and corresponding value-vector in Python, so for n=3 you have to give parameters `["rCWall2.T[1]", "rCWall2.T[2]", "rCWall2.T[3]"]` and `[TStartWall[1], TStartWall[2], TStartWall[3]]`, and in case of multiple parameters concatenate such vectors.